# Nested switch cases

Tags: javascript

I am currently getting an error or nothing shows up. Please help...

```
function getTotal()
{
var service = prompt("What service would you like? ", " ");
var options = prompt("How frequent do you want the service? ", " ");
var contractLength = prompt("How long do you want the contract?" , " ");
var totalPrice = " ";
    switch (service) {
        case 'Lawn Maintenance':
            switch (options) {
                case 'Montly':
                    switch (contractLength) {
                        case '6':
                            totalPrice = $25 }
                            }
    break; }
```

Comment: `totalPrice = $25` ... do you have a variable called `$25`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`switch`es, especially nested ones, are going to make things much, much more complicated and hard-to-read than they need to be. Consider using an object indexed by options instead, for example:

```
function getTotal() {
  var service = prompt("What service would you like? ", " ");
  var frequency = prompt("How frequent do you want the service? ", " ");
  var contractLength = prompt("How long do you want the contract?", " ");
  const services = {
    'Lawn Maintenance': {
      'Monthly': {
        '3': 15,
        '6': 25
      },
      'Yearly': {
        '3': 5,
        '6': 10
      }
      // etc
    }
  }
  const serviceObj = services[service];
  if (!serviceObj) throw new Error('Invalid service');
  const frequencyObj = serviceObj[frequency];
  if (!frequencyObj) throw new Error('Invalid frequency');
  const totalPrice = frequencyObj[contractLength];
  if (totalPrice === undefined) throw new Error('Invalid contract length');
  return '$' + totalPrice;
}
```